# Robocorp Visual studio code long path errror

Tags: python, error-handling, robotframework

getting error after downloading robocorp, an building the project
WARNING!  Long path support failed. Reason: exit status 1.
WARNING!  See https://robocorp.com/docs/product-manuals/robocorp-lab/troubleshooting#windows-has-to-have-long-filenames-support-on for more details.
Long paths do not work!

Executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe configure longpaths --enable
Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe configure longpaths --enable
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Failure to modify registry: Access is denied.

Executing: C:/Windows/System32/mshta.exe javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application');shell.ShellExecute('c:/Users/davisvin/.vscode/extensions/robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2/bin/rcc.exe', 'configure longpaths --enable', '', 'runas', 1);close();
Executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe configure longpaths
Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe configure longpaths
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: The full path of C:\Users\davisvin\AppData\Local\robocorp\stump\verylongpath1\verylongpath2\verylongpath3\verylongpath4\verylongpath5\verylongpath6\verylongpath7\verylongpath8\verylongpath9\verylongpath10\verylongpath11\verylongpath12\verylongpath13\verylongpath14\verylongpath15\verylongpath16\verylongpath17\verylongpath18\verylongpath19\verylongpath20\verylongpath21\verylongpath22\verylongpath23\verylongpath24 is too long.
WARNING!  Long path support failed. Reason: exit status 1.
WARNING!  See https://robocorp.com/docs/product-manuals/robocorp-lab/troubleshooting#windows-has-to-have-long-filenames-support-on for more details.
Long paths do not work!

There was some error with rcc configure longpaths.
Windows long paths support NOT enabled.
RCC stdout:
<not collected>
RCC stderr:
<not collected>
Extension will not be activated because Windows long paths support not enabled.
Robocorp Code extension disabled. Reason: Unable to get python to launch language server.
Unable to activate Robocorp Code extension because python executable from RCC environment was not provided.
-- Most common reason is that the environment couldn't be created due to network connectivity issues.
-- Please fix the error and restart VSCode.
Error getting Python
Unable to get language server python info.
Error: Unable to get language server python info.
at c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\vscode-client\out\extension.js:92:23
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\vscode-client\out\extension.js:23:58)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[Error - 2:08:21 PM] Starting client failed
Error: Unable to get language server python info.
at c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\vscode-client\out\extension.js:92:23
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\vscode-client\out\extension.js:23:58)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error initializing Robocorp code.
Unable to get language server python info.
Error: Unable to get language server python info.
at c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\vscode-client\out\extension.js:92:23
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\vscode-client\out\extension.js:23:58)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Robocorp Code initialization finished. Took: 21.3s
Error resolving interpreter.
command 'robocorp.resolveInterpreter' not found
Error: command 'robocorp.resolveInterpreter' not found
at b.k (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/davisvin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1669:3069)
at b.executeCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/davisvin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1669:2985)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error resolving interpreter.
command 'robocorp.resolveInterpreter' not found
Error: command 'robocorp.resolveInterpreter' not found
at b.k (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/davisvin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1669:3069)
at b.executeCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/davisvin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1669:2985)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe feedback metric -t vscode -n vscode.code.error -v ERROR_INITIALIZING_ROBOCORP_CODE_LANG_SERVER
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Tracking is disabled. Quitting.

Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe feedback metric -t vscode -n vscode.code.error -v ACT_RESOLVE_INTERPRETER
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Tracking is disabled. Quitting.

Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe feedback metric -t vscode -n vscode.code.error -v INIT_NO_PYTHON_LANGUAGE_SERVER
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Tracking is disabled. Quitting.

Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe feedback metric -t vscode -n vscode.lsp.error -v EXT_UNABLE_TO_START
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Tracking is disabled. Quitting.

Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe feedback metric -t vscode -n vscode.code.error -v INIT_NO_LONGPATH_SUPPORT
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Tracking is disabled. Quitting.

Error executing: c:\Users\davisvin\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robocorp-code-0.40.2\bin\rcc.exe feedback metric -t vscode -n vscode.code.error -v INIT_PYTHON_ERR
Error code: undefined
Error: error
Stderr: Tracking is disabled. Quitting.

So I manually enabled longs path on powershell, regedit and gpedit windows 10 and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > NTFS > Enable Win32 long paths`
2. Select `Enabled`, then click `Apply`.